# ftell() function giving wrong answer

Tags: c, file

when I run the program and gave 3 characters then the output is showing there are 9 characters. what is wrong in the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        FILE *fp;
        char c;
        fp=fopen("random","w");
        while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
        {
            putc(c,fp);
        }
        printf("no of character entered = %ld\n",ftell(fp));
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

Comment: Try change `c` to `int`. `EOF` value is `-1` and might not work with `char`.

Comment: Change `putc(c,fp);` to `putc(c,fp); printf("%d\n", c);` and report findings.